# How to add transition animations when presenting new Controller in Cyborg?

Tags: android, cyborg

So I'm using the createNewLayerBuilder line and the new controller just pops up without an animation.

```
createNewLayerBuilder().setControllerType(ControllerName.class).build();
```

How do I add one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just requires a small addition:
A duration for the animation, and use of setStackTransitionAnimators(StackTransitionAnimator... stackTransitionAnimators).
For example:

```
createNewLayerBuilder().setControllerType(ControllerOfYourChoice.class).setDuration(400).setStackTransitionAnimators(createLayerTransition(PredefinedTransitions.Fade)).build();
```

Hope it helps!